# multiple if statements within an if statement all relying on input?

Tags: python, if-statement, input

my goal is for each input to activate each print
the current code:

```
import time

P = 95

west = 'west'

north = 'north'

south = 'south'

east = 'east'

lamp = 'lamp' 'light fixture' 'lamp'

grab = 'grab', 'get,', 'retrive','take'

go = 'go', 'tavel', 'walk', 'run'

put_down = 'place', 'drop', 'put'
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
#*similarity functions*#
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
  return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
#print("wait for it")
#time.sleep(10)
#print("i just wasted 10 seconds of your life")
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
def lampIn(stat):
  return 'lamp' in stat or 'light fixture' in stat

def grabIn(stat):
  return 'grab' in stat or 'get,' in stat or 'retrive' in stat or 'take' in stat

def westIn(stat):
  return 'west' in stat

def northIn(stat):
  return 'north' in stat

def southIn(stat):
  return 'south' in stat

def eastIn(stat):
  return 'east' in stat

def grabIn(stat):
  return 'grab' in stat or 'get' in stat or 'retrieve' in stat or 'take' in stat

def goIn(stat):
  return 'go' in stat or 'travel' in stat or 'walk' in stat or 'run'

def put_downIn(stat):
  return 'place' in stat or 'drop' in stat or 'put' in stat
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
while True:
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
  statement = input() 
  statement = statement.lower()
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
  resultGrab = similar(grab, statement)
  grabResult = grabIn(statement)

  for grabResult in statement or resultGrab >= P:
    print("what are you getting?")
    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
    statement = input() 
    statement = statement.lower()
    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
    resultLamp = similar(lamp, statement)
    lampResult = lampIn(statement)

    for lampResult in statement or resultLamp >= P:
      print("you now have the lamp")
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
  resultGo = similar(go, statement)
  goResult = goIn(statement)

  for goResult in statement or resultGo >= P:
    print("Where?")
    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
    statement = input() 
    statement = statement.lower()
    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
    resultWest = similar(west, statement)
    westResult = westIn(statement)
    for westResult in statement or resultWest >= P:
      print("You went west.")

else: print("not a command yet")
```

the result:

```
>>>walk
  what are you getting?
  est
  you now have the lamp
  you now have the lamp
  you now have the lamp
  you now have the lamp
  what are you getting?
```

the result im trying to achieve:

```
>>>walk
   where?
   west
   you went west
```

while also maintaining each individual path

Comment: A `for` statement is not the least bit interchangeable with an `if` statement.  You are looping over the *characters* of `statement`, which makes no sense at all.

Comment: Please shrink down the code to what's needed to cause the problem, by removing parts that are irrelevant to the problem.